# php unique id within a month

Tags: php

I need unique id (as much unique as possible) during a month and during one year. Code must be short. Code is necessary for accounting software as identification number of entry/record.

Aim is to get it unique if company during a month has not more than 10 000 transactions. Also aim is that code must be as short as possible and also php code is as short as possible and uses as little server resources as possible.

Mysql autoincrement can not be used, for example if 10 000 transactions per month, then after some years the number would be very long.

At the moment decided to use such

```
 date("m"). '-' .substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), -20, 4);
```

Are any better solution?

Comment: and what after month? I'd prefix it with year as well

Comment: Why a random ID instead of an "incremental numeric ID" reset to 0 at the beginning of each month? With only 4 random characters (0-9 a-f) the risk of "collision" looks relatively high.

Comment: I suppose year is not necessary, because it would be very long. An accountant or bookkeeper must write it on each document. So id must be as short as possible. If the same id would be in Year 2013 and 2014 i think it is not problem. Id is necessary to find entry in software. Such is our legislation requirements. Someone see id on document and asks accountant: show me where it is recorded in software.

Comment: I would go with an incrementing id and the month and year, for example: 02-2013-123456 really isn't that bad

Comment: You keep saying "code should be short", but not how why etc. Suppose you save this in a database. Just use an incremental id. If you save your id as an Unsigned INT, it does not claim more resources to store the shorter numbers, and you can go up to `4294967295` .. that's a lot of 10k months.

Comment: Thanks for advice Frosty Z. So incremental numeric ID would be based on number in mysql? On page load connect to mysql, get last number.... need to think what would be code to check month and reset

Comment: @user2232696 You _do not need to reset your auto increment and you shouldn't_. Not only is this entirely pointless (see answers below), but it also makes ALL of your code **more complicated** (you need to query by month and ID instead of just ID).

Comment: "As much unique as possible" - you can't compare the level of uniqueness, either it's unique or it's not :)

Comment: If you use letter/number combos (ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789 - I removed I-O-0-1), 3 characters can give you 39,304 unique combinations. So, that would be YYYYMM-XXX, a total of 10 characters, if you want to include year, which I think is prudent. I would also auto-increment the letter/number combo.

Comment: @Vlad Preda, I dunno about that.  You can certainly measure the average number of duplicates as a function of number of entries.

Comment: @user2232696 as others suggest, you should primarily rely on a auto-increment ID (like what MySQL provides). Optionally, following end users wishes, you can add a 'user-friendly' field which format would be something like what suggested Tony (as comment) or Narek (as answer).

Comment: @FoolishSeth: You are correct, but not really talking about uniqueness. If you had a single duplicate, or 1000, it wouldn't make a difference, they wouldn't be unique either way. There is only one way for a value to be unique.

Comment: @FoolishSeth: At that point you're no longer unique. It's like pregnancy - no half measures!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would submit that you are fooling yourself. A standard mysql auto-increment (INT) will go up to 4,294,967,296. So, at a rate of 10k transactions per month, that'll only last you for 35,791 years.

Now of course, if that's insufficient you can use a BIGINT, in which case you'll have  153,722,867,280,912 years to figure things out. That's quite a few times longer than the predicted lifespan of the universe.

This sort of thing is the EXACT use case for an auto-increment.

Comment: +1 ,OMG Lolw't  ... i am sure i will die before 35,791 years.

Comment: Best answer ever :) You deserve a cookie

Answer (score 3):

After **50** years your ID will be **50x12x10.000 = 6.000.000**. It's very small ID for `mysql`.

If you don't want to show that long ID to your users you can do [dechex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

```
$userFriendlyId = dechex($id);
```

and make queries from user friendly id with [hexdec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)

```
die(dechex(6000000)); //will output 5b8d80
```

Or other [converting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), thanks to John.

Comment: Or some other form of base converting to get even more letters, but dechex with will.

Comment: Sure, that just for example.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would go for an auto increment too. Even if you choose to use a code as mentioned (month + random stuff) I would advise to also use a numeric (int/bigint) auto increment id. You should use this id 'below the surface' for your code to communicate with the database (referencing/looking up records).

So for the 'month + random stuff' identifier I wouldn't advice to use anything with `uniqid()` for it is based on microseconds and not unique if two transactions would take place at the same microsecond. Also I would discourage the use of `md5()`, because this function would be very useful for hashing, but slows your code down a lot if you'd only use it for generating chars.

Also your own code suggestion generates 4 random chars that could be 0-9 or a-f (hexadecimal) which gives you 16 possibilities. 4 chars of 16 possibilities gives you 16x16x16x16 = 65,536 unique strings. It would be highly possible that when rendering 10,000 of these strings you'd get duplicates.

I would advice to generate a random string yourself from the chars 0-9, a-z and A-Z, which gives you 36 possibilities per char and with 4 chars gives you 36x36x36x36 = 1,679,616 unique strings. More chars gives you less probability for duplicates (collision). You could do such thing like this:

```
function randString($length = 4) {
    $randChars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randString = ''; 
    while (strlen($randString) < abs(intval($length))) {
        $randString .= substr($randChars, rand(0, strlen($randChars)-1), 1); 
    }   
    return $randString;
}

$id = date('m') . randString(4);
```

I would also leave out the dash ('`-`') between the month and the random chars because this saves you 1 char and you know the first two chars will always be the number of the month.

**Edit: done some tests**

I've done some testing for the collision:
I've rendered 10,000 random strings a hundred times and checked the uniqueness every time. Done this with length 3, 4 (as you did), 5 and 6.
So here are the results:

```
-------- Length 3 ------------
Minimal duplicates: 170
Maximum duplicates: 241
Average duplicates: 207.05
-------- Length 4 ------------
Minimal duplicates: 0
Maximum duplicates: 8
Average duplicates: 3.19
-------- Length 5 ------------
Minimal duplicates: 0
Maximum duplicates: 2
Average duplicates: 0.05
-------- Length 6 ------------
Minimal duplicates: 0
Maximum duplicates: 0
Average duplicates: 0
```

Absolute 0% chance of collision can't be ruled out as also pointed out by [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903606/php-unique-id-within-a-month#comment22648410_15903739) referring to the Birthday Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). its designed to generate globally unique values, not just unique for each month or year.

Comment: Any function which outputs a finite set of values can not possibly guarantee uniqueness, just FYI. In fact, there is a principle that directly contradicts your claim: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: a) They are already using `uniqid`.  b) If you're going to make a claim that it is 100% unique, provide the proof, as it does not meet that claim.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. 100% isn't quite true - though for this use case (<10,000/month) it would be.

Comment: @Jon they are using uniqueid as part of the string. why? why not just use it plain?

Comment: True, however, why not just use the auto-increment as well as it will more than suit the needs. ^^

Comment: @jon I voted auto increment up :) put this answer as a secondary option

Comment: @MrGlass Same.  And true, using it by itself would be better than what they are currently doing - was just surprised at the 100% comment as I've never seen a claim for 100% before (most are 99% or 99.99% etc :P ) lol

Answer (score 0):

```
date("m").'-'.time().rand(0,9999)
```

will be enought, i think.

Comment: no. it won't be. read up on the birthday paradox: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Absolutely not - birthday paradox makes this A LOT less successful than you expect.

Comment: you have time() - unique 10-digit for each second and a random number from 0 to 9999. You will get duplicate only in cases, when you have more than hundreds requests per second.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few digit hash

```
 $random_hash = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 10, 10);
 echo date('m-Y-').$random_hash ;
```

but I don't.
A combination of unique primary key with date('m-Y') in the output might be much better for accounting reasons.

Answer (score -1):

What about using the company id, which Im sure you guys have, with the month/year and md5 them, then take the first 10 chars. This will always be unique.

Comment: and will have no advantage above an auto-increment whatsoever.

Comment: Wouldn't this generate the same ID for the whole month? The question was asking about having 10,000 unique ids within a month.